# RANK function not working properly in excel

Tags: excel-formula, ranking

I am a teacher and I'm preparing a result sheet for my class. but I'm facing problems while ranking the positions. in my class 4 students are on 1st rank this is why I guess excel RANK formula is not working properly. so please I want a formula for accurate ranking like if there's 4 students are on 1st rank then the next four positions ranks (2nd,3rd,4th) should be skipped and the second highest score should rank 5th position. and so on 3rd highest score should rank 6th position. Please help me :)

Comment: Rank() works to do that.  It will rank all that are equal as the same rank and skip the the dups.  Please show a [mcve] which would include the formula you tried and the output it is giving that is in error.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rank-function-6a2fc49d-1831-4a03-9d8c-c279cf99f723)  RANK should do exactly what you want. Can you please add your data, the formula you used, and the expected and observed result. Just tried. Works as expected

Comment: No.. As I mentioned the highest marks in my class is 167 and 4 students score 167 marks so tha 1st rank goes to them... Then 2nd 3rd and 4th position should skip and 5th position goes to the students score 166 marks.. But idk why in my sheet excel rank is giving 1st rank to 166 score too... And many many more errors

Comment: I can't be able to share a pic what can i doo

Comment: You could for instance post the data as a table and add the formula you are using. And also post the result as a table